# How does Tensorflow do quantization and dequantization?

Tags: tensorflow

According to the blog post "https://petewarden.com/2016/05/03/how-to-quantize-neural-networks-with-tensorflow/", Tensorflow quantizes values before they go into a layer. After being processed by the layer, the values are dequantized. Tensorflow quantizes values by rescaling the values between 0 and 255, so it needs to keep "min" and "max" to dequantize the values.

I would like to ask:
1. how the "min" and "max" in the outputs of a "quantization" op are determined? I mean, if we simply find the minimum and maximum value and set them to 0 and 255, we will get data overflow or underflow when doing convolution.
2. how the "min" and "max" in the outputs of a "convolution" op are determined? Both weights and activations are quantized, so there are two sets of "min" and "max". How does a convolution op combine them to form a single set of "min" and "max"?

Answer (score 3):

TensorFlow uses i.a. [gemmlowp](https://github.com/google/gemmlowp) for low-precision matrix multiplications. Although 8-bit values are used as inputs, intermediate results are 32-bit values. These 32-bit values are converted back to 8-bit before returning the results.

From https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/blob/master/doc/low-precision.md :

> To avoid overflow, we internally accumulate results on more than 8 bits, and at the end we keep only some significant 8 bits.

Comment: How gemmlowp selects right kernel for low-precision gemm when inputs are less then full 8bit range? (There was commit https://github.com/google/gemmlowp/commit/4746387c02f2b9542fe5d4a6ac4bb4d81f88ef15#diff-69cce824f316d701d9c3c23afcb00694 to disable requantizing for less-than-8-bit modes: "*from now on, using actual less-than-8-bit settings will only have the effect of selecting a different GEMM kernel. ..it is now the responsibility of the user to know the actual bit-depth (i.e. range) of their 8bit values. ... users ..will enjoy the increased performance of corresponding kernels*)